# SBT Plugin: How to add compiler plugin as a dependency that is not propagated downstream?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macros, sbt-plugin, scala-macro-paradise

I'm writing a SBT plugin. I would like to use Circe JSON library, but it requires the Macro Paradise compiler plugin on Scala 2.10.

Normally you add compiler plugins to `build.sbt` and SBT plugins to `project/plugins.sbt`.

Now when you're building a SBT plugin, the other plugins become dependencies, so you put them to `build.sbt` and they are propagated to the projects where you use your SBT plugin.

When I put the following snippet in `build.sbt` of my SBT plugin:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Does the Paradise compiler plugin propagate to downstream projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler plugins are not propagated by default, but they will in fact be required by downstream users as a dependency, and there is no way for you to bypass this requirement.

The reason is simple, their code will be compiled in a different compilation unit, so as long as you have features that depend on the compiler plugin that will be found in the end codebase, you'll also need to stick a note on this plugin to explicitly add the dependency.

Hope this helps, and take for example the really popular Monocle lib [**here**](http://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/). Annotations won't expand without paradise for instance, so it's all a question of what the end user will need.

**Quote**

If you want to use macro annotations such as @Lenses, you will also need to include:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" %% "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Comment: How do you force the propagation ? In my case I do want the `addCompilerPlugin` added in my plugin to be propagated downstream to the consumer of the plugin.

Comment: @Wonay I don't think you can, unless there's some SBT setting where you can force it to keep this in the classpath.